# Git rebase - how do I accept remote branch for all merge conflicts?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'm working with my_branch_1 using git 1.7.1, and I'm trying to rebase from master.  I have some changes of my own in directory_1.

When I attempt:

```
git rebase master
```

from my branch, I get large number of merge conflicts (over 200) from files in directory_2.  How these conflicts got there, I have no idea.  I also have no way of knowing how the conflicts should be corrected since they are all in files I've never opened and don't know anything about.

Ideally, I'd love to be able to tell git: "hey git - if you hit a merge conflict in directory_2, just take the file from master, don't ask me about fixing it".

At this point, I'd even be ok with just accepting master for ALL merge conflicts, as most of my work has been with new files.  How do I automatically tell git to rebase and resolve all conflicts by using files from master?

Comment: Kdiff3 is a pretty handy tool. Supports directory merges for selective but not over manual operations. However, if you don't know about them, why not merge in prior to the rebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is do a `git merge master`. This will generate the merge conflicts. Then you can use a little shell magic to do the rest with `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U`. This command will list all the files with conflicts. So you can do something like

```
$ git merge master
$ git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | grep ^path/to/directory_2 | xargs -I% sh -c 'git checkout -f HEAD -- % && git add %'
```

And then you may finish merging

Or you can do the other way

```
$ git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | grep ^path/to/directory_2 | xargs -I sh -c 'git checkout -f master -- % && git add %'
```

The first does `ours` on the directory `directory_2`, and the second does `theirs` on the directory `directory_2`.

What this script does is get all the unresolved conflicts, filters with `grep` so that only the ones that are in `directory_2` are in the list, and then uses `xargs` to run the command `git checkout -f <branch: Either HEAD or master> -- <file> && git add <file>` for each file in the list.

Comment: This mostly fixed the problem.  After merging  and adding selected files I still had a few rebase errors.  These were resolved by checking out the effected files from master and then running git rebase --skip.

Comment: If I run the second command on Mac OS X I get `xargs: illegal option -- c`. How do I prevent this error?

Comment: And if I run the first one, I get `fatal: pathspec '%' did not match any files`.

Comment: It seems the second command is missing `-I%`, and I just forgot to remove the grep when I ran the first one lol.